# variance of doubly truncated binomial

Tags: estimation

I am in need of variance of doubly truncated binomial distribution (equation number 3.69 on page number 137 of third edition of Johnson, Kemp and Kotz Discrete Probability Distributions).

Thanks.
Anwer

Answer (score 2):

Let $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$ with pmf $f(x)$:

[image]

Let $a$ and $b$ denote the lower and upper points of truncation, such that $a \leq X \leq b$.

Then, $P(a \leq X \leq b)$ is:

[image]

where I am using the `Prob` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to do the nitty-gritties.

Then, the pmf of the doubly truncated random variable $X$ s.t. $a \leq X \leq b$, with pmf denoted $g(x)$, is:

[image]

Finally, we seek $\text{Var}_g(X)$:

[image]

All done. The solution output can be viewed LARGER here:

http://www.tri.org.au/se/varianceofdoublytruncatedBinomial.png

**Quick Plot**

Just to make sure the result makes sense, here is a quick plot of the solution just derived -- the variance of the doubly truncated Binomial -- when $n = 12, p = \frac34, b= 12$, as the lower bound $a$ increases from 0 to 12. The thin red horizontal line is the unconditional variance of the Binomial parent  (i.e. $np(1-p)$ ), and the the blue dots are the variance of the doubly truncated model, as the lower bound $a$ increases. As one would expect, the variance of the bounded model should be smaller than the unconstrained model. All looks fine.

[image]

**Notes**

1. The `Prob` and `Var` function used above are from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*.
2. The variance calculation took about 10 hours to compute on a 2014 R2-D2 Mac Pro, though much of this would have been 'simplification' time.
3. Details on the `Hypergeometric2F1` etc functions can be found here:  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html

Comment: (+1) I was so surprised at the ten hour calculation time that, to understand what the problem might be, I did this computation directly (from the definitions). A fresh kernel for *Mathematica* 9.0.1 completed it in 4.8 seconds on a four-year-old Windows 64 workstation.  However, the expression it obtained for the numerator is a little more complicated (involving 21 hypergeometric function calls), so it looks like the extra ten hours of computation was used for simplification.

Comment: @whuber Just had a quick look. Yes - almost all of the timing is `FullSimplify`. Under Mma 9, the total time is 15 minutes. Under Mma 10, the same calculation took 10 hours - aha (running overnight). There does seem to be some bug or problem with `FullSimplify` under the new Mma 10.